# Independent sources of information on radiation pollution in Europe

Tags: air-pollution, pollution, radioactivity

Bear with me if this is a wrong place to ask this question. I aksed this question on Physics at StackExchange and was told it will be more on topic here.

Recent news show a fire has started close to the former nuclear plant in Chernobyl because someone was burning grass. Ukrainian State Scientific and Technical Center for Nuclear and Radiation Safety [explained](https://sstc.ua/news/rozrahunkovi-trayektoriyi-rozpovsyudzhennya-potencijno-zabrudnenogo-povitrya-na-osnovi-onovlenih-danih):

> the fire in the exclusion zone has been extinguished. [...] The updated modeling results indicate that the potential maximum concentrations of Cs-137 in the surface layer in Kyiv were lower than 0.1 mBq/m3. The forecasted concentrations are less than those observed previously and more than 1000 times lower than the acceptable levels established by NRBU-97. They do not pose any harm to the health of the population.

The information has been [confirmed](https://www.paa.gov.pl/aktualnosc-546-komunikat_paa_w_zwiazku_z_pojawiajacymi.html) (translation mine) by Polish National Atomic Energy Agency:

> With regard to false information appearing in public space about the alleged occurrence of radioactive contamination in Poland, the National Atomic Energy Agency strongly denies this type of information. The radiation situation in the territory of the Republic of Poland remains normal. There is no threat to the health and life of the population in the country.

On the other hand, we have received contradicting information from several friends, family and "trusted" sources that there was a threat to our safety and we should stay at home for two days and close the doors and windows to avoid contamination. I consider this fake news, but I am also aware that sometimes governmental agencies delay notifying the public because of political or other reasons. For instance, when there was Chernobyl disaster in 1986, some scientist at one of Polish physics institute had access to Geiger counter. They started to carry over their own measurements of contamination but they were told to stop doing that by the institute authorities that there connected to the Communist Party at that time.

There used to be a similar problem with smog air pollution in my and other European countries. There were some governmental measurements of air pollution but there was also some controversy how they measured air pollution, how frequently they reported it and how they defined safety thresholds. In a response to that problem multiple companies started to produce low-cost devices that you can install at your home to measure air pollution. This provides a source of information independent from governmental agencies.

Is there similar initiative, agencies, companies, etc. that measure radiation pollution in Europe?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right forum, but I have seen in the past decades how quickly for instance Scandinavian countries, Germany, Britain, France and other countries react when radiation levels rise above normal, even giving hints from where it comes based on isotopic composition. The first instance to check would probably be the https://www.iaea.org/, and environmental groups and organisations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two websites I've come across that might be of interest are:

- [Radioactivity Environmental Monitoring Joint Research Centre](https://remon.jrc.ec.europa.eu/), for Europe.
- [Radmon.org](https://radmon.org/index.php) which provides radiation information from number of
  global station.

Comment: Radmon.org seems to be what I was looking for. I wonder what green color means in the map. Does it green radiation is low or that the station is operational? I''m missing a legend there.

Comment: There other question is how to convert CPM to Sv/h which are used to assess abnormal radiation. According to https://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/q11784.html, to convert one unit to another to unit to know the device used for measurement, and since stations in Radmon network are amatour people are using different devices of diverse sensitivity.

Comment: There's also another amateur initiative similar to Radmon: http://radioactiveathome.org/map/.